# Trying to create multiple ENI and attach it to EC2 instance

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create EC2 and attach more than one ENI to it. Each EC2 instance will be created in different AWS avalability zone.

EC2 creation is woring and I am able to create EC2 in multiple availability zones.

when I try to add multiple ENI support to code, I am facing "You may not attach a network interface to an instance if they are not in the same availability zone" error.

my main.tf code

```
resource "aws_security_group" "security_group" {
  name                                      = var.test_security_group_name
  vpc_id                                    = var.test_vpc_id
}

resource "aws_instance" "ec2_instance" {
  count                                     = var.test_instance_count
  ami                                       = "ami-006dcf34c09e50022"
  availability_zone                         = element(var.test_availability_zones, count.index % 2)
  subnet_id                                 = element(var.test_subnet_ids, count.index % 2)
  instance_type                             = "t2.medium"
  security_groups                           = [aws_security_group.security_group.id]
  depends_on                                = [
    aws_security_group.security_group
 ]
}

resource "aws_network_interface" "network_interface" {
  count                                    = var.test_is_multi_eni ? var.test_instance_count * var.test_eni_count : 0
  subnet_id                                = element(aws_instance.ec2_instance.*.subnet_id, floor(count.index / var.test_eni_count))
  security_groups                          = [aws_security_group.security_group.id]
/*
  attachment {
    instance                               = element(aws_instance.ec2_instance.*.id, floor(count.index / var.test_eni_count))
    device_index                           = count.index + 1
  }
*/
}

resource "aws_network_interface_attachment" "network_interface_attach" {
  count                = var.test_instance_count * var.test_eni_count
  instance_id          = element(aws_instance.ec2_instance.*.id, floor(count.index / var.test_eni_count))
  network_interface_id = element(aws_network_interface.network_interface[*].id, floor(count.index / var.test_eni_count ))
  device_index         = count.index + 1
}

output "instance_id_ip_address" {
  value                                    = zipmap(aws_instance.ec2_instance.*.id,aws_instance.ec2_instance.*.private_ip)
}
```

my variable file

```
variable "test_instance_count" {
  type        = number
  default     = 1
}

variable "test_availability_zones" {
  type        = list(any)
}

variable "test_subnet_ids" {
  type        = list(any)
}

variable "test_vpc_id" {
  type        = string
}

variable "test_security_group_name" {
  type        = string
}

variable "test_is_multi_eni" {
  type        = bool
}

variable "test_eni_count" {
  type        = number
}
```

my terraform.tfvars file

```
test_instance_count           = 2
test_subnet_ids               = ["subnet-11111111111111111","subnet-2222222222222222222"]
test_availability_zones       = ["us-east-1a","us-east-1b"]
test_vpc_id                   = "vpc-11111111111111111"
test_security_group_name      = "project_sg"
test_is_multi_eni             = true
test_eni_count                = 2
```

I am getting following error.

```
 Error: attaching EC2 Network Interface (eni-001d0888d329349ef/i-06a19b6020b5e0452): InvalidParameterCombination: You may not attach a network interface to an instance if they are not in the same availability zone
│       status code: 400, request id: cc16f140-d02c-4d51-b597-fcc306a0f2b0
│
│   with aws_network_interface_attachment.network_interface_attach[2],
│   on main.tf line 31, in resource "aws_network_interface_attachment" "network_interface_attach":
│   31: resource "aws_network_interface_attachment" "network_interface_attach" {
│
╵
╷
│ Error: attaching EC2 Network Interface (eni-001d0888d329349ef/i-06a19b6020b5e0452): InvalidParameterCombination: You may not attach a network interface to an instance if they are not in the same availability zone
│       status code: 400, request id: 57e978c3-7c73-4770-9438-90bb1812387c
│
│   with aws_network_interface_attachment.network_interface_attach[3],
│   on main.tf line 31, in resource "aws_network_interface_attachment" "network_interface_attach":
│   31: resource "aws_network_interface_attachment" "network_interface_attach" {
│
╵
╷
│ Error: attaching EC2 Network Interface (eni-03907626a2330b64b/i-03009cf1bb500e422): InvalidNetworkInterface.InUse: The network interface 'eni-03907626a2330b64b' is currently in-use.
│       status code: 400, request id: 1b468e4b-a8a3-4527-830f-02c4f00b7678
│
│   with aws_network_interface_attachment.network_interface_attach[0],
│   on main.tf line 31, in resource "aws_network_interface_attachment" "network_interface_attach":
│   31: resource "aws_network_interface_attachment" "network_interface_attach" {
│
```

I have used same logic for EBS volume and it is working.

Edit:

Thanks. I have changed it from "element(aws_network_interface.network_interface[*].id, floor(count.index / var.test_eni_count ))" to "aws_network_interface.network_interface[count.index].id".

Now it is fine. Logically it is trying to attach ENIs properly to right EC2 instancem but failing because device_index now.

it is expecting device_index to 1 and 2 for each EC2 instance, but it producting 3 and 4.

I need get output like below for device_index.

```
-----------------------------------------
count index    ENI count    device index
-----------------------------------------
   0               4             1
   1               4             2

   2               4             1
   3               4             2
-----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach maximum three ENIs to the `t2.medium` instance. However, you are trying to attach four ENIs to your instance. Check out this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html) to see how many ENIs can be attached to which instance.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But my requirement is that I need two EC2 instance and each instance should have 3 ENI (1 primary created during EC2 creation and 2 secondary ), so I am creating 4 ENI (instance count X ENI count) and trying to attach 2 ENIs to each instance. This is my requirement.

Comment: There might be something wrong with `element(aws_network_interface.network_interface[*].id, floor(count.index / var.test_eni_count ))` In the list, there are four ENIs, but it chooses the same one twice. The `floor` should be replaced with another operator that yields consecutive values each time.

Comment: after modifying code, it is failing now because of device_index.

Comment: Try to use `condition ?` expression. If `count.index` is an even number, then the device index is 1, else 2. You can use the modulo operator to find if `count.index` is even or odd.

Answer (score 0):

After adding condition to device_index, it is working.

```
resource "aws_network_interface_attachment" "network_interface_attach" {
  count                = var.test_instance_count * var.test_eni_count
  instance_id          = element(aws_instance.ec2_instance.*.id, floor(count.index / var.test_eni_count))
  network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.network_interface[count.index].id
  device_index         = count.index % 2 == 0 ? 1 : 2
}
```

Thanks a lot, to hsaltan.